# Difference between the presence and allow_blank validators in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out the difference between:

```
validates :foo, presence: false
validates :foo, allow_blank: true
```

When I use presence: false validation fails but when I use allow_blank: true it does not. According to the docs http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of uses the blank? method. Can someone please explain the difference?

Comment: You described the difference between these expressions quite precisely.

Comment: If presence uses `blank?` then surely `presence: true` means `foo` can not be nil and `presence: false` means `foo` can be nil. But when I use `presence: false` and `foo` is nil it fails.

Answer (score 4):

First case:

```
validates :foo, presence: false
```

it does not validate the presence of `:foo` at all.

`nil, '', 'anything'` are all valid.

Second case: `:allow_blank` is an option, not a validator.

It skips validation if the attribute is blank (more [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates)).

If you want to know how it works, you can see the [code here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2bb0abbec0e4abe843131f188129a1189b1bf714/activemodel/lib/active_model/validator.rb#L150).

Before call the selected validator, it checks the attribute is not blank, if it's then skip validation.

The only reason why it works as a validator is the way that source code is written.

At any moment Rails' team can change the code and `:allow_blank` stop working as a validator.

Comment: So what *does* `validates :foo, presence: false` validate, then?

Comment: It does Nothing. This line of [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b13a5cb83ea00d6a3d71320fd276ca21049c2544/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L115) does nothing if `option` is `false`. Because, `validations` in line 114 is `{precence: false}`. Then `:foo` is always valid. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`allow_blank` only validates `nil`, `presence` validates `nil` as well as `empty`